# HTTP ERROR 404 dotnet core API with Docker

Tags: c#, .net, docker, asp.net-core, .net-core

I'm trying to run a dotnet web API inside a docker container, but when i run it i can't navigate to the site, i get `HTTP ERROR 404` in the browser.

This is my dockerfile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:2.2-stretch-slim AS base
WORKDIR /app

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:2.2-stretch AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY Backend/AppManagerAPI/AppManagerAPI.csproj Backend/AppManagerAPI/
COPY Backend/DTO/DTO.csproj Backend/DTO/
COPY nuget.config ./
COPY Build/dependencies.props Build/
COPY Directory.Build.props ./
COPY ./*.sln ./
COPY Backend/Database/Database.csproj Backend/Database/
COPY Backend/Service/Service.csproj Backend/Service/
COPY Utilities/Utilities.csproj Utilities/
RUN dotnet restore "Backend/AppManagerAPI/AppManagerAPI.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/Backend/AppManagerAPI"
RUN dotnet build "AppManagerAPI.csproj" -c Release -o /app

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "AppManagerAPI.csproj" -c Release -o /app

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app .
EXPOSE 5000
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "AppManagerAPI.dll"]
```

I added `.UseUrls("http://*:5000")` so i listen to every call from port 5000 on my program.cs:

```cs
public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }

        public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .UseStartup<Startup>()
                .UseUrls("http://*:5000");
    }
```

If i run `docker logs appmanager` i get this:

```
Hosting environment: Production
Content root path: /app
Now listening on: http://[::]:5000
Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
```

This is how i'm running my container:
`docker run -d -p 5000:5000 --name appmanager appmanager`

I've tried everything but i don't know what i'm missing...

Comment: If you run `docker logs appmanager` can you see that your API is returning a 404? If you're API is returning a 404 then it is a programming issue inside your API. If it's not your API that's returning the 404 then you are not pointing at the service you think you are.

Comment: If i run ```docker logs appmanager``` im getting the log that i mentioned in my question. @RB.

Comment: What is your request url? Is there any demo to reproduce your issue?

Answer (score 0):

found the issue - the problem was with csproj settings-file.

After  removed all Microsoft.* PackageReferences and added only this one:

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
```

Everything started working as expected! :)

Comment: had the same issue, there were four PackageReferences in my csproj file, I removed the other three and rebuilt and restarted docker and retried and nothing changed. Did you change anything else to get it working?
Also, the other references were Razor, Container Tools and Json, how should they not be required?

Comment: I have no clue how this helped to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

check out the takeaways of these methods

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapDefaultControllerRoute();
});
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).